# How to create a descriptive text for a post in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, substring

I want to create a description of the post. This description is taken from the content of the post, which may include html tags but I want not to include the *html* tags like `<html>`, `<script>` and so on.

**For example:**
I have some content as follows:

```
<html>ajsdhasudhasidyuai</html>
```

and I want to get the first 2 characters and without the `<html>` tag, so the result should be

```
aj
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: So, now we know what you want to do. What have you tried? What problem are you facing? What kind of help do you need?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "excerpt".

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with PHP code:

`$extract = substr( strip_tags($content), 0, 2);`

This will:

- Strip all HTML tags from your *content* string
- Take the first 2 chars (substring) from the clean content
- Return `aj` for your given example.

You may want to create a *helper* function or *class* to achieve this but this is your starting point.

[See example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1902cfae33d85477124a7c097e1753356ff0c72a)

Comment: Yes. Thank you help me.

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to mark as answered and refer to related questions for further info.